# running shutdown.bat shuts down wrong Tomcat instance

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I have 2 tomcat instances configured. 1 as a service and one stand-alone. If I shutdown the standalone tomcat installation using shutdown.bat in the /bin folder then both the standalone and the Tomcat service is stopped.

Has anyone encountered this before?

I don't have any Tomcat/Catalina environment variables configured and I'm using Tomcat6 on both installs...

Comment: check $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml, if both are using same ports (shutdown port, listen port, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two instances of Tomcat are listening on different ports. They also should listen on different ports for the shutdown signal. Make sure that the port referred in the shutdown.bat file matches the port configured in the instance of Tomcat that you are trying to shut down.